# How can I solve, error:unknown filesytem grub rescue>

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

I was previously using Win7 and had two partitions on my hard disk. After learning about Ubuntu I decide to remove Windows and install Ubuntu 11.10 instead. All my important files and documents are stored in my second partition. After successful installation, during restart I get the error :

```
error: unknown filesystem grub rescue>
```

Please help me to resolve the problem, and note that I don't want dual boot my machine.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

1. First completely uninstall Grub.
2. Then use the Ubuntu 9.10 Live CD to boot. Use the following command to boot the CD

   `$ sudo fdisk -l`
3. After the complete boot check where the Ubuntu is installed and note down the location. Then mount it using this command:

   `$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda2 /mnt`
4. Next change the Location or Directory which is of your choice.

   `$ /dev/sda2`
5. Now install the Grub again

   `$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`

**Second Method**

1. Restart the system and boot from Ubuntu 9.10.
2. After the boot you will need to edit the grub.
3. Now the computer is booting to grub. Create new command line to edit the grub. Use these commands as given below:

   `root (hd0,0)`

   `kernel /vmlinux-version ro root = /dev/hdaN`

   `initrd /initrd-version`
4. At the end press <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd> to boot it properly.
5. In the system level you will need to upgrade the GRUB. To do this use the following command:

   `$ upgrade-grub`