# grub rescue error:unknown filesystem

Tags: 12.04, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unknown filesystem error: grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124757/unknown-filesystem-error-grub-rescue)

I have a dual o.s linux(ubuntu 11.10) and windows 7.I have a problem in grub.I had done a mistake.In windows there is a option called disk management there i have deleted one of my partition and renamed it as M drive previously it was G drive. when i switch of the laptop and turned it on it is showing an error `grub rescue error : unknown file system`.please do help me i am struggling with this problem. please.i dont know what to do

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106133/how-can-i-solve-errorunknown-filesytem-grub-rescue?rq=1